# ClassNotFoundException for uneeded imported class

Tags: java, maven, jar

i'm trying to make a jar with Maven (we used to do it with ant til now).
we need two jars , one global and another CLIENT, smaller than the first one.

for the client, i exclude all unneeded jars and classes for client use. my main class, import a class from jmxtools jar, but it is needed for execution only for the big jar.

client jar is executed with JWS, here JNLPClassLoader try to load com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer (it exists in the list of imports), which is unneeded for client and i get ClassNotFoundException.

do you have any idea please ?

for more information, i'm building the project on my local machine with maven eclipse plugin.

here is a glance :

```java
...
import com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer;
...

class MyClass {
    ...     
    public void start() {
        ...
        if BIGJAR {
            HtmlAdaptorServer html = new HtmlAdaptorServer(portNumber);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

sorry for my english ^^

Comment: `it exists in the list of imports` well, you should fix that.

Comment: yes it exists because the BIG and ClIENT jars have the same main class.

Comment: to launch the BIG one we need the com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer.

Comment: but for the client , it is un needed for execution. i don't know if i'm clear enough for you :S

Comment: Either remove the reference or include the file.  (Consider referencing the "unneeded" class only through a factory that loads the class via it's String class name, accessing the resulting object only via interfaces.  This will eliminate the need to import the class or otherwise reference it in your Java source.)

Comment: i'm ok with you, but i'm trying to understand why it loading a class not used for the executed code. the jar we generate with ant script has the same class and same packages, but it works ! i think imported classes ares checked only during compliation. during execution they are checked only if an instruction needs them. i hope i'm right ...

Comment: i added a glance of my code on the original question

Comment: If you don't have a reference to the class, you don't need the import.  If you remove the import and you get a compile error you've found the problem reference.

Comment: Personaly i don't see how it can work with the ant build. Can you compare the jar made by the last ant build and the jar you get with the maven build? Are you sure the class isn't there in the jar built with the ant build?

Comment: @HotLicks : yes i do have a reference to the class. because to run the server side (BIG jar), i need this class. for the client, there is no need for it. normally when i launch the client jar throuth jnlp file, i don't need to execute the instructions calling thi missing class...i know it's not usual as problem...

Comment: @stefaandutry : yes i'm sure !

Comment: Re-read what I said about using a factory.  This is a common pattern to avoid a "hard" link to an optional class.

Comment: @HotLicks : i can't modify this class or any of the same package because it's our core system. failed to get autorisation because it works when we build with makefile. sorry it's not ant build.

Comment: Well, if you can't modify the source (not the external spec) of the class then you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If some code is not needed for the client side jar it probably shouldn't be there at all. How about separate the server and client functionality into two different classes and include only  the relevant parts in the jar?

Comment: it's not possible unfortunately, this product has been working from years... the probleme is with ant, we get the same jars, with the same packages and libraries, but it works without any problems ... i don't know what can make difference.